# In ASP.NET MVC, is UpdateModel recommended

Tags: asp.net-mvc, updatemodel

In ASP.NET MVC, UpdateModel is dreadfully convenient if not a bit too black box. One of the primary reasons I use ASP.NET MVC, however, is exactly for the insane amount of control I get compared to ASP.NET so from an ideology perspective, the black box part bothers me a bit.

Is the use of UpdateModel recommended? It's used in the (original) canonical Nerd Dinner so it obviously has somewhat of a endorsement from the powers that be but I doubt that's the final word.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Considering the code that you would have to write to update a model object (boring and repetative) Im glad that they include the feature. As it gives you control over which members to allow and which to not, its got my vote. Great feature!!!